# Delphi - mouse move simulation

Tags: delphi, mouse, move

How can I simulate mouse moves (from point x,y to point a,b), ideally 10 pixels / second?
I found `SetCursorPos` function, but this function cannot move my cursor correctly.
My goal is to move the cursor over `TWebBrowser` component and read hints with OCR (and find text that I'm looking for).

PS: I'm using Delphi 7.

Comment: You are going to read hints from a web browser content by moving mouse cursor and reading it by OCR. Well, uhm, don't you rather want to read `TITLE` attributes of all links of the shown page by DOM inspection if it is possible ?

Comment: Won't you need the other app to have the focus for this to work? Anyway, `SetCursorPos` does what you ask. Perhaps you should stop asking XY questions.

Comment: You need to use ClientToScreen function in order to convert your TWebBrowser Point to the Desktop (Screen) Point , then SetCursorPos function will works correcly .

Comment: SetCursorPos moves cursor correctly. If you show the code and describe what coordinates you need and what you get, then maybe someone will able to help you. Without it we can only guess what are you doing with this function and why it doesn't make you happy or hippie...